# Java: How to store and transfer huge Integer-ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

My Java application has to work with very large ArrayLists full of integer values. Manipulating these ArrayLists is not a problem, but these ArrayLists also need to be transmitted and stored, which I haven't found an efficient way to do yet.

The list consists largely of consecutive integer values, for example:

```
1 -> 5000
2 -> 5001
3 -> 5002
4 -> 5003
5 -> 5005
6 -> 5006
7 -> 5007
```

So I would have imagined that the list could e.g. be transferred as follows: "5000-5003; 5005-5007". Then I could put them back together into a list at the other end. Unfortunately, the list is not sorted.

How can one efficiently compress the list to save it in a database or in text form and transfer it to another device?

Comment: Sounds like run-length encoding could help.

Comment: "Unfortunately, the list is not sorted." does it have to be reconstructed in the same unsorted form?

Comment: How large is "very large"?

Comment: Could you sort the list? Or does position matter? In any case a kind of RLE could help, e.g. store an int, int pair which state `start + number of elements`. That means `5000-5003` could be expressed as `5000,4` and `5005-5007` would become `5005,3`. If the average number of elements could be very low using an int,byte pair would even be more efficient - larger sequences could still be represented as smaller chunks (e.g. `0-300` could become `0,255,255,46`). Of course this only works if there are sequences and the list is sorted to some extent, otherwise you could as well send individual ints.

Comment: @AndyTurner No, the List does not have to be reconstructed in the same order. Very Large means somewhere between 2 and 8 million records.

Comment: You could implement your own `List` class that both encapsulates sorting functionality and records the cases where element N - (element N -1) != 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the information i have at the moment, the best solution would be to write a class Map which looks like this:

```
public class Map {
    public final int offset;
    public final int length;

    public Map(int off, int len) {
        offset = off;
        length = len;
    }
}
```

And a loop which encodes all integers to a map object:

```
List<Map> mapList = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.sort(list);
int[] array = list.toArray(new int[0]);
int index = 0;

while(index < array.length) {
    int off = array[index];
    int len = 1;

    for(int i = 1; index + i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[index + i] != array[index] + i) break;
        len++;
    }

    mapList.add(new Map(off, len);
    index += len;
}

Map[] maps = mapList.toArray(new Map[0]);
```

You need to write a method which parses the map into a String or similar, but for that i do not have sufficient information.

Comment: Thank you so much - that is a perfect solution. Would you mind to explain why you copied the sorted list to an int-array instead of just iterating the list itself? Thank you!

Comment: But doesn't this code still add every single number to the map, just with different "len"? - Wouldn't you need to increment the "index" somewhere?

Comment: Hold up, yes i forgot the index increment there. The reason for copying the ArrayList into an array is, that arrays are much faster to iterate over, especially if indexes are picked out multiple times (i.e. in the if checks)